# c programme is not print out desired output

Tags: c, cs50

I wrote this code in C as a problem set from CS50, problem needed to be solved was to write a programme that can check if a credit card is valid and then if the card is valid identify ether the card is VISA,AMERICAN EXPRESS OR MASTERCARD.
I wrote the algorithim to check if the card number is valid and is printing invalid if the card number is invialid. My problem is that my code doesn't wanna print out the name is card is

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
long card;
//prompt the user for card number
do
{
    card = get_long("Card no: ");
}
while (card < 0); // card number must always be greater than zero

//count digit starting from second-last then multiply by two
int card1,card2,card3,card4,card5,card6,card7,card8;

card1 = ((card % 100)/10 * 2);
card2 = ((card % 10000)/1000 * 2);
card3 = ((card % 1000000)/100000 * 2);
card4 = ((card % 100000000)/10000000 * 2);
card5 = ((card % 10000000000)/1000000000 * 2);
card6 = ((card % 1000000000000)/100000000000 * 2);
card7 = ((card % 100000000000000)/10000000000000 * 2);
card8 = ((card % 10000000000000000)/1000000000000000 * 2);

card1 = (card1 % 100 / 10) + (card1 % 10);
card2 = (card2 % 100 / 10) + (card2 % 10);
card3 = (card3 % 100 / 10) + (card3 % 10);
card4 = (card4 % 100 / 10) + (card4 % 10);
card5 = (card5 % 100 / 10) + (card5 % 10);
card6 = (card6 % 100 / 10) + (card6 % 10);
card7 = (card7 % 100 / 10) + (card7 % 10);
card8 = (card8 % 100 / 10) + (card8 % 10);

int sum1 = card1 + card2 + card3 + card4 + card5 + card6 + card7 + card8;

//find digits that where not multiplyed by two
int card9,card10,card11,card12,card13,card14,card15,card16;

card9 = (card % 10);
card10 = ((card % 1000)/100);
card11 = ((card % 100000)/10000);
card12 = ((card % 10000000)/1000000);
card13 = ((card % 1000000000)/100000000);
card14 = ((card % 100000000000)/10000000000);
card15 = ((card % 10000000000000)/1000000000000);
card16 = ((card % 1000000000000000)/100000000000000);

int card9,card10,card11,card12,card13,card14,card15,card16;

card9 = (card % 10);
card10 = ((card % 1000)/100);
card11 = ((card % 100000)/10000);
card12 = ((card % 10000000)/1000000);
card13 = ((card % 1000000000)/100000000);
card14 = ((card % 100000000000)/10000000000);
card15 = ((card % 10000000000000)/1000000000000);
card16 = ((card % 1000000000000000)/100000000000000);

int sum2 = card9 + card10 + card11 + card12 + card13

c
18th Jan 2023, 12:39 PM
Khulyso Dev®
Khulyso Dev® - avatar
3 Answers

Sort by: Votes
Answer
0
you mean I should first write code on sololearn playground and then share a link, the one I posted above I wrote it using VS code
18th Jan 2023, 2:53 PM
Khulyso Dev®
Khulyso Dev® - avatar
0


int sum2 = card9 + card10 + card11 + card12 + card13 + card14 + card15 + card16;
int sum3 = sum1 + sum2;

int length = 0;
long visa = card;
long amex = card;
long master = card;


if((sum3 % 10)!= 0)
{
    printf("INVALID\n");
    return 0;
}


//Differetiate between visa,master and Amex
while (card >0)
{
    card = card / 10;
    length++;
}

//Identify if its VISA
while (visa >= 0)
{
    visa /= 10;
}
if (visa == 4 && (length == 13 || length == 16))
{
    printf("VISA\n");
    return 0;
}

//identify if its Amex
while (amex >= 10000000000000)
{
    amex /= 10000000000000;
}
if (length == 15 && (amex == 34 || amex == 37))
{
    printf("AMEX\n");
    return 0;
}

//identify if its mastercard
while (master >= 100000000000000)
{
    master /= 100000000000000;
}
if (length == 16 && (master == 51 || master == 52 || master == 53 || master == 54 || master == 55))
{
    printf("MASTERCARD\n");
    return 0;
}
else
printf("INVALID\n");
return 0;
}
```

I tried to replace printf("%s\n", "VISA"); with printf("VISA\n") but is still not printing out the desired output

Comment: To be quite frank, this code is a mess. Look at how to use loops in C. As written your code is a nightmare and will be very difficult to track down any bugs. Furthermore, there are comments and Stack Overflow page contents intermingled with the rest of your code. Please edit your question and fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: Why are you treating the card number as a long?  The input is a string.  Treat it as a string.  There is no need to convert it to a numeric type, and doing so greatly complicates things.

Answer (score 0):

Time to use a debugger.
Or take a close look at this:

```
//Identify if its VISA
while (visa >= 0)
{
    visa /= 10;
}
```

This loop ends only if `visa` becomes smaller than 0, which only happens if visa was initially negative.

But the following code is entered only if `visa` is 4 - which never happens.

```
if (visa == 4 && (length == 13 || length == 16))
{
    printf("VISA\n");
    return 0;
}
```